# D3.js: How to adjust chord paths?

Tags: d3.js

The chord here intersects itself in a strange way. Is there a variable to adjust 
how the chord is drawn? The only variables I've seen in the documentation and examples seem to only specify the the basic variables to draw the chord e.g. from angle x to angle y. I tried adding interpolation as well similar to how regular svg-lines are adjusted but that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: It looks more like a bug than a configuration choice. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: @DwayneTowell Don't think I can separate this unique instance from the larger project. The rest of the circle is actually one huge blue chord btw. The graph looks fine when more nodes are added. It's just this one instance that has an issue.

Comment: Did you write the code? What geometry are you using to set the control points?

Comment: @DwayneTowell I'm just using D3's chord layout function and chord path function. (https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Chord-Layout) It doesn't seem to allow you to specify your own geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is located in line 15 of [this file](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/svg/chord.js). In general, what you want to do is use a better control point when the angle between segments is small. I have no idea what a good guess for that would be, but I do know where the code would go.

Lines 51-53 compute the path for the chords. The (0,0) is a "control point" (see [this note](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataQuadraticBezierCommands)). When the start and end angles are very near each other the control point tends to pull the path too far toward the center of the diagram (the origin). So, computing a new value for "0,0" that was closer to the edge of the diagram will help. Possibly you want some kind of exponential adjustment so it "only effects small angles". Use math similar to lines 38 and 39 to find an appropriate Cartesian coordinate.

If you create a fiddle that reproduces the problem, I'll see what I can come with.

Comment: Ah thanks! I'll fiddle around and see what I can come up with. Maybe the customization option will be added in the next version of d3 as well.